# Can we use Gatsby js to build a simple social networking website

Tags: reactjs, web, gatsby, social-networking

I need to develop a simple social networking website which will just act as a platform for different businesses to discover each other. Each Business man/Service provider will have his own profile that he can manage and these profiles will be characterised and sorted according to their types. Basically I would need a Home Page, Profile page for each profile, Search page along with registration and login. I don't need to make any messaging module.

So for this purpose I wanted to know if using [Gatsbyjs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org) is a good idea, also if not then what are the other frameworks that I can use for a easier and faster development.

Answer (score 0):

One main problem with gatsby for this use case is: Once a new business signs in and wants to create and edit a new profile, this new profile is not part of the build process. Gatsby builds only the HTML pages you know in advance. Triggering a rebuild, which may take several minutes, everytime a business edits their page is not feasible. You would have to hack something together with client-side routes which is not the intended nor recommended way of doing things.

A server-side framework like [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) is better suited for this task. This way you can dynamically add and change the profile pages.